# SSRS truncating parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report that populates a parameter with a stored procedure. This query works as expected. When the parameter is used in running the report, the parameter is being truncated. I choose value ABCD, but the report returns values for ABC. The stored procedure I am passing the parameter to runs perfectly in SSMS and returns ABCD data. When I test the query in the query designer or I run the report, I get ABC data. How do I get SSRS to pass in the entire parameter?

Comment: Do string parameters have a length specified? Is it being truncated due to a data type conversion (e.g. `varchar(3)`, resulting in one character being truncated)?

Comment: the stored procedure is a varchar(6). If there's a place to set length in SSRS, I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Is there an expression, such as a substring() or left() in the text box that displays the parameter?

Comment: Did you ever set the nvarchar from the query that populates the parameters to a length of 3 in the past? The RDL file might have kept the old values for some reason, or the server was never updated with the change in length.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the datasource on your server is the same as the one in BIDS? If you made changes, it may not update because the **OverwriteDatasets** default is false. Have you deleted the **.data** file in your report folder? SSRS keeps local data to try to be helpful.

Comment: There is no expression related to the parameter.

Comment: This code was written by someone who came before me, so I cannot speak as to the initial variable length. I am running the report in BIDS and still receiving the error which leads me to believe it's not holding data. Plus, if I run it for all values, the report returns ABCD and ABC data. So I can get the data when I don't specify a value.

Comment: I do not have a data file associated with this report, so I have nothing to delete.

Comment: There's nothing in SSRS that could truncate a parameter value in the way you are describing, unless specifically coded to do so. It sounds to me like either the query behind the parameter is not returning the values you are expecting (don't confuse parameter *values* with *labels*, they might be different) or possibly the stored procedure (presumably this is what returns your main dataset) is doing some truncating of the parameter value internally. You say you have run the stored procedure and it returns the correct result, but have you verified that the report is passing the same parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are strings without a set length. There's nothing to truncate your values. Have you checked the values to make sure that the Value and Label are the same?

The **label** is what you see (ABCD) while the **value** is what is actually passed in the parameter. I don't know if that would be your problem if it works on your local machine though.

[image]

If that doesn't work you can try deleting the parameter and recreating it - it shouldn't work but has before.

Comment: He says he is getting the values from a query. I don't think this would apply.

Comment: I am using a query and the query returns the proper values. I also tried deleting and recreating the parameter with no change in the results. I also changed the parameter and hard coded just ABCD as the only value. It still returned ABC data.

Comment: Have you checked the Parameter to make sure that the **Label** and **Value** fields in the properties is set to use the same field? It seems unlikely that one field would display ABCD but have ABC in the value but...

Answer (score 0):

I had something like this happen to me before, try going into the stored proc you have and creating an output table for your parameters results to go into that is constant, i.e.

```
declare @mytable table (returnval varchar(50))
```

make sure you make one column in the table for the results of your query you will return and make sure you make the data type a varchar with enough pace to hold any possible return selection values. Note: do not use nvarchar as I find this still sometimes truncates the values and cuts things off.

you will want to execute the query the same way for the proc you originally did but this time inserting the values into your temp table i.e.

```
insert into @mytable

select * from table.name
```

this will insert all values into your temp table, also this table now has a set value length for all return values that will not change, you could try and do this the same way with the original query  by using a set length field for the table the problem is there are many factors that exist that can change this, here are a few examples.

1. If you have 2 select statements with a union to get results from both that you want to use for final results then each field may have a set length and data type that differs from the other, sql server will give the best data type in the results but when it sends the data over to ssrs it can interpret it differently as another length value unless set.
2. You may have multiple data types you are using in the return field and ssrs is getting confused which to use i.e. interger values, varchar, text, etc. this sort of reinforces the one above.
3. Also another possibility is it could be happening on the SSRS side of things and not the proc, but by doing this method you eliminate out one possible cause which is the stored proc.

Also, check in the configuration settings of your report on the back end and make sure that the return value is set from the query as it should be but also make sure that there is no setting specified for a return data type, this sometimes happens if at report design you create the report first and use a static parameter for testing to get the report created first and then you specify later the parameter is a list from a query result set which I have had happen as well.

Finally one good practice each time you make a change to something is to ensure that the report is being generated each time and not showing a cached version of the report which makes it look like nothing changes on the report each time.  the way to do this is to close the report each time or when you run the report also try and make sure you hit the reload on the page after you run the report to force a reload to make sure you see the differences each time.

I think if you do all of this you will either find the issue or eliminate it or both as I have so many times.